# Need help to write Sql update query?

Tags: sql

I need to update parent table with value from child  one

this my explanation

```
update table1 set column1 = (select name from table2 where profile = true)
where column2 in (select id from table2 where profile = true)
```

basically i need to copy name from child and set is as column1 in table1 where ids are the same in parent and child table and profile in table2 = true

Comment: Support for multi-table UPDATE statements is substantially different in different SQL databases.  Please specify which product you need a solution for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table1 
set column1 = table2.name 
FROM table1 join table2 ON table1.column2 = table2.ID
where table2.profile = true
```

[might need tweaking for your particular SQL dialect (RDBMS not specified)]

Comment: What is a `profile`? And shouldn't it be `profile = 'true'`, isn't it a string?

Comment: @VoodooChild: read the question above. I do not know the type or use of the posters columns.

Comment: Ok. I was actually just wondering as in general terms if we can query `bool` expressions in sql? (+1 btw, it does answer the OPs question)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, the Update table is virtually also in the FROM clause
SQL Server uses bit for booleans (no true/false), so I suspect you are using something else

```
update table1
set column1 = table2.name
from table2
where table1.column2 = table2.id and table2.profile = 1
```

MySQL form ( and Oracle too )

```
update table1 a join table2 b on a.column2 = b.id
set column1 = table2.name
where b.profile  # 'true = true' is silly
# b.profile = true   === just   b.profile
```

Comment: +1: however, you should clarify your comments for `MySQL form ( and Oracle too )` part because I do not follow.

Comment: @VoodooChild There's no need to say `BOOLVAR = true`.  It's redundant.  `BOOLVAR` itself is true/false and can be used on its own in a `WHERE` clause.